# Unit Testing /login in Spring MVC using MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I have a very simple REST application created using Spring MVC. (Code is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/tanidiktan/backend).) It has a simple [`WebSecurityConfigurer`](https://github.com/tanidiktan/backend/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tanidiktan/backend/config/WebSecurityConfiguration.java) as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/new").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler);
}
```

When I run the application, both the custom controllers and the login/logout pages work without a problem. I can even [unit test](https://github.com/tanidiktan/backend/blob/master/src/test/java/com/tanidiktan/backend/controller/UserControllerTest.java) `/user/new` via `MockMvc`. However, when I try to test `/login` with the following function

```
@Test
public void testUserLogin() throws Exception {
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = post("/login")
            .param("username", testUser.getUsername())
            .param("password", testUser.getPassword());
    mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(cookie().exists("JSESSIONID"));
}
```

it fails as follows:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = POST
         Request URI = /login
          Parameters = {username=[test-user-UserControllerTest], password=[test-user-UserControllerTest-password]}
             Headers = {}

             Handler:
                Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

               Async:
   Was async started = false
        Async result = null

  Resolved Exception:
                Type = org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException

        ModelAndView:
           View name = null
                View = null
               Model = null

            FlashMap:

MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 405
       Error message = Request method 'POST' not supported
             Headers = {Allow=[HEAD, GET]}
        Content type = null
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<405>
```

But I am pretty user `POST` to `/login` is working when I run the application instead of test. Further, when I try make a `GET` or `HEAD` request (as suggested in the `Headers = {Allow=[HEAD, GET]}` line of the logs), this time I receive a 404. Any ideas about what is going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: I believe /login URL is handled via spring security filter and I am not sure if you have "configured" it during your test setup

Answer (score 9):

You could use spring security testing classes to test form based login. You need to do the following to test form based login.

**Maven dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snasphot</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**Test class:**

```
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestBuilders.formLogin;

RequestBuilder requestBuilder = formLogin().user("username").password("passowrd");
mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(cookie().exists("JSESSIONID"));
```

Comment: I still get a 405. When I use `.addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain)` as @sodik suggested, this time I get a 200, but cookies are missing. (See my comment to @sodik.)

Answer (score 7):

I noticed the github link now. I believe you need to configure security filter also for your tests. Something like

```
 mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webApplicationContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain)
                .build();
```

Some additional settings might be necessary, you might check http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/integration-testing-of-spring-mvc-applications-security/ for inspiration.

Comment: this time I get the following `MockHttpServletResponse` with HTTP code 200, but the cookie is missing.

                  Status = 200
           Error message = null
                 Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY]}
            Content type = null
                    Body = 
           Forwarded URL = null
          Redirected URL = null
                 Cookies = []

Answer (score 2):

Testing SpringSession, I achieved to get the session cookie and saving session to an embedded Redis doing this:

```
@Autowired
private SessionRepositoryFilter<?> springSessionRepositoryFilter;
...

@Before
public void setup() {
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders
        .webAppContextSetup(context)
        .addFilters(springSessionRepositoryFilter)
        .apply(springSecurity())
        .build();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Following my post here:
[Spring MockMvcBuilders Security filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281272/spring-mockmvcbuilders-security-filter)

I have manage to create REST API with UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken for /oauth/token but I didn't manage to create the test for my protected resource (on running server it work fine).
Could you show us your REST interface ?

Comment: All the code is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/tanidiktan/backend), see my post.