# Spring MockMvcBuilders Security filter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-test

I have manage to create REST API with spring mvc. My purpose was about to protect a resource with JWToken.
Now i am trying to write three Test :
1. Get the Token with granted user/password Authentication Fail => test:OK 
2. Get the Token with not granted user/password Authentication success => test:OK

3. Get the protected resource without providing the Token => test:fail because my rest service give the protected resource ....

Here is my REST controller:

```
    @Component
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/protected")
public class HelloWorldRest {
    /**
     * Logger
     */
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(HelloWorldRest.class);


    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
    /**
     * permet de générer un token
     * 
     * @param idFonc
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting/{name}")
    public Greeting greeting(@PathVariable String name) {
        LOG.info("Fonction greeting : "+name);
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                        String.format(template, name+ ", je suis Mister Toto"));
    }

}
```

Here is my test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/tokenEndPointsTests.xml" })
public class tokenEndPointsTests {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private Filter resourceServerFilter;

@Before
public void setup() {
    // mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).addFilter(resourceServerFilter,"/protected").build();
}

@Test
public void testgetToken() throws Exception {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken principal = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            new Principal() {
                @Override
                public String getName() {
                    return "user";
                }

            }, null, null);
    MvcResult mvcresult = mockMvc
            .perform(
                    get("/oauth/token").param("client_id", "user")
                            .param("client_secret", "password")
                            .param("grant_type", "password")
                            .param("username", "user")
                            .param("password", "password")
                            .principal(principal)).andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
    MockHttpServletRequest mockhttp = mvcresult.getRequest();
    System.out.println(mockhttp.toString());
}

@Test
public void testgetTokenEchec() throws Exception {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken principal = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            new Principal() {
                @Override
                public String getName() {
                    // c'est le nom de l'user ...
                    return "user1";
                }

            }, null, null);
    MvcResult mvcresult = mockMvc
            .perform(
                    get("/oauth/token").param("client_id", "user")
                            .param("client_secret", "password")
                            .param("grant_type", "password")
                            .param("username", "user")
                            .param("password", "password")
                            .principal(principal)).andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized()).andReturn();
    MockHttpServletRequest mockhttp = mvcresult.getRequest();
    System.out.println(mockhttp.toString());
}


@Test
public void testgetProtectedResource() throws Exception {

    MvcResult mvcresult = mockMvc.perform(get("/protected/greeting/toto"))
            .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized())
            .andReturn();
}

}
```

Here is my tokenEndPointsTests:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sample" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />



<mvc:annotation-driven />
<sec:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" />
    <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>

<sec:http pattern="/protected/**" create-session="never"
entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/protected/**" />

    <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
    before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="springsec/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">
</bean>

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider
    user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService">
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientDetails"
    class="com.sample.context.security.InMemoryClientDetailsServiceSample">
</bean>



<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" />
</oauth:authorization-server>


<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<bean id="tokenStore"
class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="JwttokenConverter"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="JwttokenConverter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter" />
    <bean id="tokenServices" class="com.sample.context.security.JWTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="false" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="3600"></property>
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    <property name="accessTokenEnhancer" ref="JwttokenConverter"></property>
</bean>



</beans>
```

It seem resourceServerFilter is not used during testgetProtectedResource().

Thank for reading me :).

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a few issues that are apparent to me.

**Use springSecurityFilterChain**

Instead of using resourceServerFilter, you should use springSecurityFilterChain which contains the authorization rules.

**Map the Security Filter to `"/**"`**

The mapping for MockMvc's Filter is mapped only to /protected, but it should be mapped to every URL. Internally Spring Security will only invoke the necessary Filters.

A summary of the two changes can be found below:

```
MockMvc mockMvc;

// use springSecurityFilterChain
@Autowired
private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
       .webAppContextSetup(context)
       // Use springSecurityFilterChain & remove "/protected"
       .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain)
       .build();
}
```

**Missing intercept-url@access**

The configuration is missing the intercept-url@access attribute. For example

```
<sec:http pattern="/protected/**" create-session="never"
entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />

    <!-- Ensure you define an access attribute below! -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/protected/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>

    <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
    before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>
```